# Creating a dataset

Tags: dataset, tweepy

I am trying to extract tweets from a specific hashtag, and save them in csv file. The below code works well, but I would like to split data. How can I split it.

Any advice will be highly appreciated,
Niddal

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json
import codecs
import sys


ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:


            tweet = json.loads(data)['text']

            #tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            print(tweet.translate(non_bmp_map))


            saveThis = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
            SaveFile = codecs.open('d:\\StremHash.csv','a', "utf-8")
            SaveFile.write(saveThis)
            SaveFile.write('\n')
            SaveFile.close()
            return True

        except BaseException, e:
            print ('failed on data,',str(e))
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

    twitterStream = Stream(auth, l)
    twitterStream.filter(track=[unicode("#عيدكم_مبارك","utf-8")])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what do you mean "split data"? Do you mean "access the text part of the tweet"?

Comment: I meant how to extract tweet's source, text, location, statuses_count, etc?